# css navigation bar positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation bar for a hobby website to display my photography and other interest's of mine, I'm having slight issues with the position of a drop-down bar I have.

[image: how the menu shows up when I hover over the music item]

I wanted to know how I would be able to position the drop down menu so when I hover over the music item it would show directly under it. I tried position: relevant, it did work but it shifted all the items to the left of it down to align with the drop down menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/Ly8wuws1/

```css
body{
        background-color: #333;
}
 
nav ul {
          list-style: none;
          margin: 10px;
          padding: 0;
          font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
          font-weight: bold;
}
nav li {
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 0 5px;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
          -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
          -o-transition: all 0.3s;
          transition: all 0.3s;
}
nav a {
          color: black;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
          -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
          -o-transition: all 0.3s;
          transition: all 0.3s;
}
nav a:hover {
                color: #12242d;
}
nav span {
                display: block;
                color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
 
.Inav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin-top: 20%;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
}
.Inav nav ul li {
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 0 5px;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
          -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
          -o-transition: all 0.3s;
          transition: all 0.3s;
}
.Inav nav a {
          color: black;
          position: block
          -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
          -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
          -o-transition: all 0.3s;
          transition: all 0.3s;
          text-decoration: none;
}
.Inav nav a:hover {
                color: #12242d;
}
.Inav nav span {
                color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
 
.Inav ul li:hover ul{
        display: block;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
}
.Inav ul li ul{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
}
 
.Inav ul li ul li{
        display: block;
 
}
.Inav ul ul a{
        color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="Inav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="./faq.html"><span>FAQ</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Honesty</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Rand2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Rand3</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="$"><span>Music</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Kanye</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drake</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>  
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the code above.

Comment: paste your code in question and make a JS fiddle you will start getting answer from user

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/, http://codepen.io or something similar to see the code

Comment: http://jsbin.com/rijiduhebe/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `position: relevant` to the parent list items, then add positioning `top` and `left` on the sub menu.

```
nav li {
    position: relative;
}
.Inav ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;   /* modify as necessary */
    left: 0px;   /* modify as necessary */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/Ly8wuws1/1/

Comment: Thank-you! I was stuck on this for hours.